# PHP image conversion JPG/GIF/PNG to BMP / ICO

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick, bmp, ico

I am wondering how do you convert JPG,GIF and PNG images into real .ICO's. I say this because lots of scripts out there just rename the file which does nothing to change the binary structure of the file which as a result yields an invalid ico that browsers don't pick up on for say, the purpose of a functional favicon.ico

From all I've read and found so far, PHP handles GIF, JPG AND PNG very well, but when it comes to BMP (the format you need to get to before porting over to ICO) - only WBMP is natively supported (WMPB is a crappy monochrome format which is nothing like the real BMP).

The other threads in stackoverflow point to wbmp, not bmp...so here I am

Cheers
G

Comment: use imagick to conver different format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can do this conversion (and it's free)

Comment: not exactly an overly specific answer but it lead me in the right direction